# Ember and immediately-invoked functions

Tags: ember.js

I just joined a team which has been building an Ember app. They're in the early stages of development, but what's caught my eye is that all of their objects are wrapped in closures:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  App.Document = DS.Model.extend({
    uri: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
  });
}());
```

I know for 'use strict' you'd wrap the object. But otherwise, is this really necessary? My previous Ember apps were build using CoffeeScript, and I believe it automatically does this when transpiled.

Also, wonder if there's a way to do this in one place, like the manifest file, and not have to do this in each and every file in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically done to isolate modules from one another, since JavaScript variables are scoped at the function level.

If your team is able, you should switch the app over to [Ember CLI](http://www.ember-cli.com), which takes care of this kind of stuff for you (plus, a whole lot more).